# cabal install ghc-mod fails

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghc-mod

Running Haskell platform 8.0.1 on Windows 10-64;
everything seems fine, but "cabal install ghc-mod" fails;
(cabal-install version 1.24.0.0)

```
>cabal install ghc-mod
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
Failed to install old-time-1.1.0.3
Build log ( C:\Users\guthrie\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\old-time-1.1.0.3.log ):
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
checking for gcc... e:\PLang\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/cabal-tmp-7812/old-time-1.1.0.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\guthrie\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-7812\old-time-1.1.0.3'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cpphs-1.20.3 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
ghc-mod-5.7.0.0 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
haskell-src-exts-1.18.2 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
hlint-1.9.41 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
old-time-1.1.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
```

However the gcc compiler does seem to run fine, and the directory path to it is correct.

There are a lot of similar problem reports like this on cabal install ghc.mod, but they all had different errors than this (that I found).

Comment: Well, have you checked what the config.log says for more details?

Comment: @Cubic- No additional information in the old-time.log, and I don't find any config.log file anywhere.

Comment: Random guess: the autoconf script doesn't give a damn about windows, and paths with spaces aren't allowed. This is really the fault of ghc-mod for depending on a long deprecated package, but you can't really expect to avoid dependency hell with such a monstrosity of a package if you want 'backward-compatibility'.

Comment: Wow - good job - fixed it. many thanks.

Comment: Surprising because the Windows install package, puts a space in the install path! (../Haskell Package). I had to take it out, change all the environment references, and then it worked.